# how to use RxBinding & Retrofit?

Tags: rx-android, retrofit2

here is my code :

```
// Observable from RxView
RxView.clicks(mBtnLogin)
            .throttleFirst(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .subscribe(new Action1<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void call(Void aVoid) {
                    String userName = mEditUserName.getText().toString();
                    String passWord = mEditPassWord.getText().toString();

                    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(userName)) {
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, R.string.input_user_name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return;
                    }

                    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(passWord)) {
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, R.string.input_pass_word, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return;
                    }

                    LoginAction action = Constants.retrofit().create(LoginAction.class);
                    // Observable from Retrofit
                    Observable<String> call = action.login(userName, MD5.encode(passWord));
                    call.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                            .subscribe(new Observer<String>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onCompleted() {
                                    System.out.println("completed");
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onNext(String s) {
                                    System.out.println("next" + s);
                                }
                            });
                }
            });
```

Is there any way you could combine the Observable from RxView and the Observable from retrofit ?

i think the code is ugly and Do not meet the ReactiveX's specifications.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you would use the `.flatMap()` operator:

```
RxView.clicks(mButton)
                .throttleFirst(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .flatMap(new Func1<Void, Observable<Response>>() {
                    @Override
                    public Observable<Response> call(Void aVoid) {
                        return apiService.getResponse().subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());
                    }
                })
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe();
```

would look a bit better with lambdas:

```
RxView.clicks(mButton)
                .throttleFirst(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .flatMap(aVoid -> apiService.getResponse().subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()))
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe();
```

Comment: what is the 'apiService'? the http request must at the background thread,then get username and password at the mainthread,how to do this?

Comment: In my example `apiService` is the service you create using Retrofit. It makes the call on a background thread using `Schedulers.io()` and then observes the results back on the main thread.

Comment: but you must get username and password when RxView.clicks(mButton),you forget the step.

Comment: Ok, then get the username and password when you make your network request. I've already shown you how to combine Observables.

Comment: i think i know the problem.the flatMap() on the mainthread,the apiService on the background thread.thanks.

Comment: Why do you need throttle first function?

Comment: You don't need to, it was simply what the OP was doing in the original code.

Comment: How does this look when using Butterknife ? I've got the @Click and @OnFocusChange that could use some `.throttleFirst()`

Comment: @SomeoneSomewhere Take a look at the [RxBinding](https://github.com/JakeWharton/RxBinding) library.